# Vectors of 2 planes

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

We have two vectors
a= 3cm
b= 4cm
Angle between the vectors= 60 degrees.
However there is another vector that is perpendicular to the plane of a and b and
c= 5cm.

Now I need to find the length of a+b+c.

I already calculated it and got 7.01cm from this $$\sqrt{3^2+4^2+5^2}$$
however in the book it says 7.87cm, I'm worried that I understood the concept wrong. Did I need to use the angles somehow?

This is the question in the book:

> The vectors a and b have the length 3 cm and 4 cm, respectively, and
>   have an angle of 60 °on. The vector c stands vertically on the plane
>   spanned by a and b and is 5 cm long. Use a construction to determine
>   the length of a + b + c.

And the sketch in the solution:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$|a+b|^2 = (a+b)\cdot (a+b ) =a^2 + b^2 +2a\cdot b=3^2+4^2+2\cdot3\cdot4\cos60=37$$

Then

$$|a+b+c|=\sqrt{c^2+|a+b|^2}= \sqrt{5^2+37} =\sqrt{62} \approx 7.874$$

Comment: I understand yours a bit better! One question, why can't we just use$2\left(3\cdot 4\right)$instead of $2\left(3\cdot 4cos60^{\circ }\right)$

Comment: @Recca - 2(3\cdot4) only works if a and b are perpendicular. The cosine term is needed if they are not.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Without loss of generality:

${\bf a} = (3,0,0)$

${\bf b} = 4 (\cos \pi/3, \sin \pi/3, 0)$

${\bf c} = (0,0,5)$

${\bf a} + {\bf b} + {\bf c} = (5, 2 \sqrt{3}, 5)$

and $|{\bf a} + {\bf b} + {\bf c}| = 7.87401.$

---

Your answer is wrong because your formula assumes the vectors are mutually perpendicular, which is explicitly *not* the case.

Comment: why is b=4(cosπ/3,sinπ/3,0)? How did you get this?

Comment: $\pi/3$ radians $= 60^\circ$